# Trello request api

Tags: php, api, trello

Здравствуйте за акцент извиние есть такой ситуация хочу отправить запрос на трело кей и токен есть у и ид есть но мне пишет что неверний ид
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
   $query = array(
       'key' => '**********',
       'token' => '********'
   );

   $response = Tre::get(
       'https://api.trello.com/1/actions/{uF67Hzah}',
       $query
   );

   dd($response);
```

Answer (score 2):

Id параметр должен быть без фигурных скобок

```
$response = Tre::get(
    'https://api.trello.com/1/actions/uF67Hzah',
    $query
);
```